# Creating java packages for Android projects

Tags: android, package

I created  multiple packages to better structure our Android-based project. After creating these packages, the application no longer runs. It's a widget application. I noticed that the application manifest needed to be modified and did so. This didn't seem to fix the problem. I don't get any error messages, I'm simply not able to open the main activity page from the application widget. Could anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

For more detail, I initially had a flat project structure (com.domain.A). Now I have the following:

com.domain.Activities

- Activity1.java
- Activity2.java

com.domain.Features

- Feature1.java
- Feature2.java

com.domain.Services

- Service_1.java
- Service_2.java

etc...

Here's an excerpt from the manifest file:

```
 <activity android:name="com.domain.Activities.Activity1"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
            android:label="@string/act1"
            />
 <activity android:name="com.domain.Activities.Activity2"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
            android:label="@string/act2"
            />

 <activity android:name="com.domain.Features.Feature1"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
            android:label="@string/fea1"
            />
 <activity android:name="com.domain.Features.Feature2"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
            android:label="@string/fea2"
            />

 <service android:name="com.cmu.Services.Service_1"/>
 <service android:name="com.cmu.Services.Service_2"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify a `package` in your manifest, then you can just use the `.` prefix to reference the package for the `Activities` you define in you manifest.  So for example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.domain"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activities.Activity1" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.Activity2" />
```

You main launcher activity is thus: `com.domain.activities.MainActivity` and the other two are: `com.domain.activities.Activity1` and `com.domain.activities.Activity2`

Answer (score 1):

After moving the classes in packages, how have you defined the activities in the manifest. 
(as a thumb rule ctrl+click on activity declaration in manifest should take you to class file, else link is broken), its generally better to keep all classes extending Activity in main android package of your app

EDIT:

if your MyActivity lies under package a.b;

then .a.b.MyActivity is to be used for android:name in manifest  the dot(.) initially specifies to use package-prefix from manifest package name..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution. If the manifest doesn't take me to a class file, how do I fix the link? My activity classes do extend Activity. I also tried to clean my project but this doesn't work either.

Comment: updated my answer, if prob remains, post your single activity declaration of android manifest and sample activity class with pkg name..

Comment: I've updated my question accordingly - it seems like my application needs a refresh. Again, the application is a widget and the activities are launched via an ImageButton on the Activity